# Gnome Disks - "ATA Enchanced Secure Erase" disabled

Tags: udisks, disk-formatting

The "ATA Enchanced Secure Erase" option for my SSD is disabled in the Gnome Disks utility on Ubuntu 22.04 - how to enable it?

Comment: Where do you see this option in "Gnome Disks"? I haven't found any on my system.

Comment: It shows up when you'd like to format a drive. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVc90.png

Comment: Sorry. I haven't tested or know for sure, but maybe your SSD does not support this.

Comment: It does support it, I was able to run the hdparm command manually to do the same operation.